# Qt Creater can't find header from the DDK (WDK)

Tags: qt, include, qt-creator, wdk

Actually I try to configure Qt Creater for the ddk.
I've added the includepath in the project configuration file,
but if I try to include a header, for example the ntddk.h he can't find it.
But where is the problem? I've downloaded the ddk form msdn.
As include folder I've added this path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km"
with "INCLUDEPATH += C:\Pro...". What I do wrong?

Comment: Has someone an idea?

Comment: Change `"\"` to `"/"`: `INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Include/km`. Then run qmake and build again.